# CSS3 animation strange behaviour in chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a `CSS3` animation which rotates a div with image in background.

On hover I want to use the same animation with different speed.

This is the code I'm using for achieving it:

```
.rocket{
  background: url('http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/d/l96/m/mR3-h7oYVSGGYNTBiKJbtMQ.jpg') no-repeat center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation : spin 1500ms linear infinite;
          animation : spin 1500ms linear infinite;
}



.rocket:hover{
  -webkit-animation : spin 500ms linear infinite;
          animation : spin 500ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
 <div class="rocket"></div>
```

But to my surprise the hover animation works only in `firefox` and not in `chrome`.
For a temporary fix I created one more animation for hover with different name and it works fine:

```
.rocket{
  background: url('http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/d/l96/m/mR3-h7oYVSGGYNTBiKJbtMQ.jpg') no-repeat center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation : spin 1500ms linear infinite;
          animation : spin 1500ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rocket:hover{
  -webkit-animation : spin2 500ms linear infinite;
          animation : spin2 500ms linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin2{
  from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Can you tell me why this is happening and how I can use the same animation with hover in chrome?

[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/redage/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I think it's a bug related to several reported similar issues that seem to be rolled into: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422909

Comment: It's really a browser bug ... I created an issue to help track this https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429138

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser bug that is related to chrome there has been an issue filed to fix it. So your best bet is to find a work around for the bug which you seem to have already done so until the browser bug is fixed just keep using your workaround.